# How to use ThemeData for text but with individual changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my App, I am using ThemeData for text styling. Now I have the problem that I want some text elements to use special attributes than what is given trough the ThemeData. In my example I want a text element to have a different font size than the regular text element. What I currently have is following:

```
Text(
       localText,
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
    ),
```

but instead of the regular font size given for this style, it should use:

```
fontSize: ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).fontSize(3)
```

How do I "combine" these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.copyWith()`, example:

```
Text(
       localText,
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
           fontSize: ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).fontSize(3)
       ),
    ),
```